# Retrieve or Specify output file name in electron-builder

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron, electron-builder

I am working with electron-builder programmatically to generate installation packages.  So far I have this as my utility to create the installation package for the current OS type:

```
const packagejson = require("../package.json");
const builder = require("electron-builder");
const Platform = builder.Platform;

function buildPromise(){
    //Development package.json
    const devMetadata  = packagejson.electronBuilder;

    //Application package.json
    const appMetadata = {
        name: packagejson.name,
        version: packagejson.version,
        description: packagejson.description,
        author: packagejson.author,
        productName: packagejson.productName
    };

    //Build for the current target and send back promise
    return builder.build({
        projectDir: "./",
        devMetadata,
        appMetadata
    });

}

module.exports = { 
    buildPromise,
    outputPath : packagejson.electronBuilder.directories.output
};
```

What it does is pull in the needed metadata from the apps MAIN `package.json` file which contains this section (so the application `package.json` is empty):

```
  ...
  "electronBuilder": {
    "build": {
      "productName": "Node App",
      "appId": "my.id",
      "asar": false,
      "win": {
        "iconUrl": "http://localhost:5000/images/logo-multi.ico",
        "target": "nsis"
      },
      "nsis" :{
        "oneClick": false
      }
    },
    "directories": {
      "output": "electron/output",
      "app":"electron/app",
      "buildResources": "electron/buildResources"
    }
  }
  ...
```

When I run the build in Windows I get a file out called `Node App Setup 1.0.0.exe`.  So far so go.  But how do I actually control that final file name?  Or at least retrieve that file name programmatically so I can read it in and respond to the client in some way?  Obviously, I could piece it together from the json file settings but it I would rather it be more definitive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At my request the author added it to the current version (8.5.1):

https://github.com/electron-userland/electron-builder/issues/899

so now we can do:

```
builder.build()
    .then(paths => {
        //paths contains an array of export file paths, e.g.:
        console.log(paths[0]); //= c:/MyProject/dist/My Project Setup 1.0.0.exe
        console.log(paths[1]); //= c:/MyProject/dist/myproject-1.0.0-x86_64.AppImage
    });
```

Answer (score 32):

You can specify the output filename using `artifactName` in the `build` section of your `package.json`.

The docs say the [artifact file name template](https://www.electron.build/configuration/configuration) supports the `${ext}` macro:

> ${ext} macro is supported in addition to [file macros](https://www.electron.build/file-patterns#file-macros).

#### File Macros

> You can use macros in the file patterns, artifact file name patterns and publish configuration url:
>
> `${arch}` — expanded to `ia32`, `x64`. If no arch, macro will be removed from your pattern with leading space, - and _ (so, you don't need to worry and can reuse pattern).
>   `${os}` — expanded to mac, linux or win according to target platform.
>   `${name}` – package.json name.
>   `${productName}` — Sanitized product name.
>   `${version}` — from package.json
>   `${channel}` — detected prerelease component from version (e.g. beta).
>   `${env.ENV_NAME}` — any environment variable.
>   Any property of AppInfo (e.g. buildVersion, buildNumber).

#### Example

```
"build": {
    "appId": "com.electron.app.my",
    "artifactName": "node-app-${version}.${ext}",
    ...
},
```

If your package version is 1.0.0, a Windows target would output:

`node-app-1.0.0.exe`